How can I unregister AddHttpClient<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>();
I am doing end-to-end testing using WebApplicationFactory and need to have my test host app unregister the following
services.AddHttpClient<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>();

I will then reregister like this
        services
            .AddHttpClient<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>()
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ => MockSendGridHttpMessageHandler);


Can anyone tell me how to unregister the services added via the previous .AddHttpClient<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>()?

Any specific way how are you testing it? Are you using WebApplicationFactory?

@dropoutcoder Yes, that's what I am using

Which NuGet package are you using? I see SendGridClient in official SendGrid package, but also in SendGridClient package. Or is it your own implementation?

To override HttpClient behavior during test run while using WebApplicationFactory you want to modify services inside ConfigureTestServices method.
You can do it while intializing client for API for specific test(s).
var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(
        services =>
        {
            services
                .AddHttpClient<ISendGridClient, SendGridClient>()
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new MockSendGridHttpMessageHandler());
        })).CreateClient();

Or you can implement custom WebApplicationFactory to apply changes in one place and then use this implementation in test classes where you need that specific behavior.
namespace DropoutCoder.HttpClientHandlerReplacement.Tests
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using System.Net;

    internal class ApiApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(builder =>
                {
                    builder.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new MockSendGridHttpMessageHandler());
                });
            });
        }
    }
}

Be aware that configuring default client using ConfigureHttpClientDefaults method will override every HttpClient registered through AddHttpClient.
I have created full sample with default, named and typed HttClient registration that can be found in dropoutcoder/webapplicationfactory-httpclienthandler-replacement repository on GitHub.
